# Jquery on change not working on input field type range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a `input` with type `range` and try to refresh the innerHTML of an output field with id `output` with the selected value, each time when the value changes.

I solved it like this:

```js
function regler()
{
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("regler").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="regler" value="0" type="range" onchange="regler()">
<p id="output"></p>
```

This works. But if i try it with Jquery then nothing happens:

```js
$("#regler").on
(
  "change", 
  function(event)
  { 
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("regler").value; 
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="regler" value="0" type="range">
<p id="output"></p>
```

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I just noticed that the code runs well on SO but not on my local webserver?

**EDIT2**: Why is my range field looking like this (Tested with Chrome and Firefox):

[image]

Instead like this:

[image]

Comment: [Seems to work ok](https://jsfiddle.net/m979tdww/), other than logging an error that the inline `onchange` attribute points to a now non-existent function.  Did you include jQuery correctly?  Any other errors in your console?

Comment: are you add  jquery.min.js  in your page

Comment: Yes i include it correctly and there are no network errors, all files were able to load and no errors in the console.

Comment: Type of Input in image is "number".

Comment: no, both are type "range"

Comment: What is input in first image? Do you want to set value of range in it?

Comment: The input in the first image is also of type "range", i don't know why, but on SO and JSFIDDLE it looks like in the second image, but hosted on my local webserver it looks like in the first image :/?

Comment: the slider input is new since html5 - so have you the correct doctype declaration in the beginning of your document? <!DOCTYPE html> should fit. if it's still <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> or something like that this results in the textarea

Comment: Yes i have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the first line. Maybe i should update apache?

Comment: dunno if this would help, since the html gets rendered by your browser, not your webserver...

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem is that i include `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js` after my normal `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` script. Now after i changed the order, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The problem is that i include `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js` after my normal `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` script.

After i changed the order, it works. Sorry for not mentioning that i include `jquery.mobile`, i did not knew that this file has something to do with the problem.

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html to make sure, that everything works fine, you should try that runnig order: Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. Thus, we recommend linking to your JavaScript files in the following order:
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>